# Scheduling app: to add all day option or not?

Tags: usability, gui-design, calendar

If a person wants to schedule something all day on Tuesday, Friday, and Saturday, should they enter 12 AM to 12 AM, or click on an “all day” checkbox instead?

[image: Scheduling app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding times to an all-day event seems clumsy. It requires adjusting two drop-downs (maybe four) and takes some cognitive energy since it's an unusual interaction. I have two calendar applications open right now and they both use a checkbox for All Day.